# Object { code: -32000, message: "unknown account" } while sending transaction to smart contract

Tags: web3js, metamask, nodejs

I know there are many questions revolving around same. But none of the answers are concrete.

I have deployed my contract using remix on BSC test net and now making frontend to interact with my contract.
Contract link: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xf897f4f3dfc002f92075f63e36d5e50752849264#writeContract

The contract is perfectly working fine I tested connecting my metamask on BSC testnet write contract.

```
function isInstalled() {
  if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
  console.log('MetaMask is installed!');
   address = ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
   //console.log(address);
}


}


web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545"));

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
//contractInstance = bet.at("");
// console.log(bet);
async function betbull()
{
    console.log("i m in function");
    var betamount=document.getElementById('betamount').value;


    abi = JSON.parse('[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_adminAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_operatorAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_minBetAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_oracleUpdateAllowance","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"currentEpoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"BetBear","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"currentEpoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"BetBull","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"currentEpoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Claim","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ClaimTreasury","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"blockNumber","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"price","type":"int256"}],"name":"EndRound","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"blockNumber","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"price","type":"int256"}],"name":"LockRound","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"minBetAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"MinBetAmountUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Paused","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardRate","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"treasuryRate","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RatesUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardBaseCalAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"treasuryAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RewardsCalculated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"blockNumber","type":"uint256"}],"name":"StartRound","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Unpaused","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TOTAL_RATE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"adminAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"referer","type":"address"}],"name":"betBear","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"referer","type":"address"}],"name":"betBull","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"claim","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"claimReferralRewards","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"claimTreasury","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"claimable","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"currentEpoch","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"executeRound","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"","type":"int256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisLockOnce","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisLockRound","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"","type":"int256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisStartOnce","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisStartRound","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"cursor","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"size","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getUserRounds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"ledger","outputs":[{"internalType":"enum BnbPricePrediction.Position","name":"position","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"claimed","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"minBetAmount","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"operatorAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"oracleLatestRoundId","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"oracleUpdateAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"referrals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"rewardRate","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"rounds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"startBlock","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"lockBlock","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"endBlock","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"lockPrice","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"closePrice","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"totalAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"bullAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"bearAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardBaseCalAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"oracleCalled","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_adminAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setAdmin","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_minBetAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setMinBetAmount","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_operatorAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setOperator","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_oracle","type":"address"}],"name":"setOracle","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_oracleUpdateAllowance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setOracleUpdateAllowance","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_rewardRate","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setRewardRate","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_treasuryRate","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setTreasuryRate","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"treasuryAmount","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"treasuryRate","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"userRounds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]');
let bet = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,"0xf897f4f3dfc002f92075f63e36d5e50752849264"); 
 
console.log(bet);
    myContractAddress = "0xf897f4f3dfc002f92075f63e36d5e50752849264";
    address = "0xBCB60D7dc22A9F04aE73aA41915B552cdfC1D24D";
    account = address;
    mydata = bet.methods.betBull('0xBCB60D7dc22A9F04aE73aA41915B552cdfC1D24D').encodeABI();
    web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: address,
    to: myContractAddress,
    gas: 2500000,
    data: mydata
})





    

}
```

now this  web3.eth.sendTransaction is throwing unknown account error. i have checked everything but could not debug

Metamask is not evening opening
although to connect in starting I am able to connect

any help would be great. Thanks

using
web3 js version 1.xx
http-server